# Paginate sorting by association count in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to sort a paginate by the count of associated objects.

I tried to use something like:

```
$query=$this->Posts->find('all',['contain'=>['Comments'=>
function ($q) {return $q -> count();  } ]]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that will actually get to work - also it's quite resource heavy.

If it's something you will do often, I'd take a look at [the CakePHP CounterCache](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html) behavior, and just use that field! :)

If you don't want to do that, you can do a `COUNT()` in the SELECT statement, and use that field in the order query.